# What happened behind when using the same db connection in multi-threads?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing

- Before put up this question, I have searched a lot about "sharing the same db connection across threads". The answers I got most are negative and use connection pool instead, but few explain in detail why we can't do this.
- Then I write a sample code using multiprocessing and multithread, I'm tring to figure it out, but there is still some difficulty to solve. Here is what I got:

  > multiprocessing:

  ```
  import multiprocessing as multiprocessing
  import pymysql
  conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='123456', db='test')

  def operate(sql):
      cur = conn.cursor()
      cur.execute(sql)
      cur.close()
      return cur.fetchall()

  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
  res = []

  for seq in range(1, 3):
      sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` = %d" % seq
      p = pool.apply_async(operate, [sql, ])
      res.append(p)


  pool.close()
  pool.join()

  conn.close()
  for j in res:
      print(j.get())
  ```

  As expected, this code does't work normally:

  ```
  ((None, None, 1, 'ttt', 'hhh', 1, 0, ''),)   # process1
  ((None, None, 2, 'zzz', '1256', 1, 0, ''),)  # process2  (1), this is normal output and should be what we want.
  ```

  ---

  ```
  ((None, None, 2, 'zzz', '1256', 1, 0, ''),)
  ((None, None, 1, 'ttt', 'hhh', 1, 0, ''),)  # (2), this is incorrect output.
  ```

  and ran for many times, either got (1) or (2). The reason (I think) is:
  though multiprocessing run in parallel, but process1 is still invoked earlier than process2. For mysql, which process' query finishes firstly is not sure. If process2's is done ealier, because they share the same connection, the connection return data following the invoked order, so I got situation (2), otherwise situation (1). Am I right?

  > multithread

  ```
  import multiprocessing.dummy as multithread
  import pymysql
  from queue import Queue

  conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='123456', db='test')

  def operate(sql):
      cur = conn.cursor()
      cur.execute(sql)
      cur.close()
      res.put(cur.fetchall())

  pool = multithread.Pool(4)
  res = Queue()

  for seq in range(1, 3):
      sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` = %d" % seq
      p = pool.apply_async(operate, [sql, ])

  pool.close()
  pool.join()

  conn.close()
  print(res.get())
  ```

  originally I think this code's result will be same to multiprocessing, but it turned out different. It printed either process1 or process2, even stucked there. Why?
- Change db isolation level to SERIALIZABLE to solve this problem?

  I tried. For multiprocessing, it seems work; but has no effect to multithread. It should work in theoretically, isn't it? If so, I will never do this anyway, but just try to find a way to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

When your python program uses a single `conn` object from inside multiple threads, it mixes up the message traffic (thread <==> MySql) from multiple threads on a single database connection. That Doesn't Work™.

MySQL connection objects aren't thread safe. Each thread needing access to MySQL must open its own connection.  (MySQL connection *pool* objects *are* thread safe though, so each thread can request, use, and release a connection from the pool safely.)

**Pro tip:** When developers of complex long-lived software (like `pymysql`) tell you it isn't thread-safe, believe them.

Comment: Thanks,  it would be more rigorous if say `it mixes up the message traffic (thread <==> MySql) from multiple threads on a single database connection` at the same time, isn't it?  And I also have noticed that there is persistent connection in Django, but how Django bind the persistent connection to current thread to prevent it used by other threads?